# Инверсия в ImageView

Tags: android, java

Можно ли через XML атрибуты сделать инверсию в ImageView? тоесть перевернуть на 180 градусов

Comment: ваш вопрос о кастомных шрифтах удалили. вот вам наименее болезненный способ замены шрифта во всем приложении
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16883281/1654690      
Однако настоятельно рекомендую разобраться, как он работает.

Comment: @Andreich, да я уже

Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/HandmadeTypewriter.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(face);

использовал. Видимо разрабам прсоот лень добавить эту сттрроку в код))). в шоке от них короче.

Comment: @ANDRO я бы не стал так опрометчиво судить. Там люди с многолетним опытом работают.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно можно.

Делается так:

1) Открываем гугл, передаём ему строку

> imageview rotate xml

2) идём по первой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11243348/3212712) и находим вот что:

> можно с версии **API 11**

В XML ImageView добавляем атрибут

```
android:rotation="180"
```

3) ???

4) Profit!!!11адын.

Comment: Тоже как вариант только я не стал ждать ответа использовал в коде rotation, а в xml почему то не додумался прописать. Но все же спасибо. это как раз ответ на вопорс

Answer (score 5):

Насколько я понял, вам нужно зеркальное отображение картинки.

В атрибутах ImageView задайте нужный scale:

```
android:scaleX="-1" //поворот по горизонтали 
android:scaleY="-1" //поворот по вертикали
```

А если в коде:

```
public Bitmap flipImage(Bitmap src, int type) { 
  Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
  // по вертикали
  if(type == FLIP_VERTICAL) {
   // y = y * -1
   matrix.preScale(1.0f, -1.0f);
  }

  // по горизонтали
  else if(type == FLIP_HORIZONTAL) {
   // x = x * -1
   matrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);

  } else {
   return null;
  }

  // Возвращаем трансформированную картинку
  return Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);
 }
```

Comment: @Nuclominus, я уже давно способ нашел imageView.rotation(180); получается поворот на 180 градусов как инверсия

Comment: Красачик! Спасибо :)